# Vim powerline plugin colour of Normal mode

Tags: vim, gvim

I installed [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) and was wondering how to change the backlground colour of the normal mode -- currently set to `#adf000` according to the Gimp -- to something else.  I assume that the change will be in `autoload/Powerline/Colorschemes/XXX.vim` somewhere, I just cannot find it.

Comment: Are you looking for the file, or the line in the file to do the change?

Comment: @M'vy: the lines to change as well as a good explanation of how it works... Hey, just like your answer in fact ^_~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colours of vim-powerline should be located in your `.vim` directory. If you use a plugin manager it may be .vim/bundle/ followed by the `vim-powerline/autoload/Powerline/Colorschemes` tree. The file you are looking for should be the `default.vim`.

The colour setting you are looking for is :

```
 .   \ Pl#Hi#Segments(['mode_indicator'], {¬        
 .   .   \ 'n': ['base03', 'green', ['bold']],¬     
 .   .   \ 'i': ['darkestcyan', 'white', ['bold']],¬
 .   .   \ 'v': ['white', 'orange', ['bold']],¬     
 .   .   \ 'r': ['white', 'violet', ['bold']],¬     
 .   .   \ 's': ['white', 'gray5', ['bold']],¬      
 .   .   \ }),¬
```

`n` is for normal, `i` for insert, `v` for visual, `r` for replace and `s` for selection(?). Additional colours can be defined in the `call Pl#Hi#Allocate({¬` section.